# Binding data to view model when dealing with DAO and Tornadofx

Tags: data-binding, kotlin, dao, tornadofx, kotlin-exposed

I am making database operations with JetBrains/Exposed. I was able to make use of the DAO approach to display data from the database on the TableView. It was quite challenging with the DSL approach.

After succeeding to display data, data binding was gone. My person class looks like this

```
class Person(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Person>(Persons)

    var name     by Persons.name
    var title by Persons.title
}
```

my view model looks like this

```
class PersonModel(person: Person?) : ViewModel() {

   val name =  bind {person?.observable(Person::name)}
   val title = bind {person?.observable(Person::title)}
}
```

Each time I want to commit a change to the model I get

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction in context.`

I know this is because Person is used in the transaction context to perform Db queries.

I wish to know how I can bind data to view model given that I am using DAO API of JetBrains/Expose.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get your answer?

Comment: I got this https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/issues/756